# Height of liquid in horizontal cylinder - volumes by integration

Tags: geometry, volume

A cylindrical gas tank with radius 10ft is lying on its side.

When the height of the (liquid) gas is 10ft, the tank is half full.

What will be the height of the gas when the tank is 1/4 full?

*I assigned a constant length of the cylinder in order to plug the values into an online calculator for find the volume of liquid in a horizontal cylinder, divide that by two, and solve for the height variable. The online calculator produced 5.96027 however, the chapter I am studying is volumes by integration & I cannot cite an online calculator. I have no idea how to do this but I am assuming it involves integration (possibly revolved a semicircle with radius 10 about the y-axis) or some other form of calculus.

Comment: Draw a picture.  Then, express the cross sectional area $A$ in terms of the depth of the cross section (they are all rectangles of the same length).  The volume is the integral of the area $A(x)$ with respect to the depth $x$.

Comment: First note that your first sentence implies the second (We do not need the second sentence to solve the problem). Also, this is not exactly volume integration, you may cast it as a 2D problem.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: The length of the cylinder doesn't matter.  All you care about is the area of the circle at the end and what fraction is covered by gas.  You need to find the height of a [circular segment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_segment) with area half of the semicircle.  You can do this without integration, just using geometry.

Comment: Ok so I found the area of the semicircle to be 50pi and obviously the area half of the semi circle is 25pi. Where do I go from here? solve for the radius using the semicircle area formula?

Comment: @Taylor:  You have the radius, that is 10 ft.  Did you look at the article on a circular segment?  The area of the segment is the difference between a "pie slice" of the circle and a triangle from the center to the points at the top of the gas.  It won't come out cleanly, you will need to do a numeric approximation.

Comment: Yes thank you! i used the formulas from wikipedia and got 5.96027265 which matches the online calculator!